# Выбор словарей списка по заданному условию

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть список словарей типа:

```js
let data = {
  "data": [
    { "name": "John", "adress": "Main st", "age": 25 },
    { "name": "John", "adress": "Victory st", "age": 27 },
    { "name": "Jane", "adress": "5 avenue st", "age": 22 },
  ],
};
```

У меня задается условие, по которому нужно либо изменить заданный список словарей, либо создать новый:

```js
let condition = {
  "condition": {
    "include": [
      { "name": "John" },
    ],
  },
};
```

На выходе должен остаться следующий список словарей:

```js
let data = {
  "data": [
    { "name": "John", "adress": "Main st", "age": 25 },
    { "name": "John", "adress": "Victory st", "age": 27 },
  ],
};
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, решение
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то вам нужно сделать не самую тривиальную логику, я бы написал примерно такое решение (для проверки вхождений я использую [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), но вам возможно будет необходимо проверять частичное вхождение, тогда лучше использовать [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)):

```js
const DATA = {
  data: [
    { name: "John", adress: "Main st", age: 25 },
    { name: "John", adress: "Victory st", age: 27 },
    { name: "Jane", adress: "5 avenue st", age: 22 },
  ],
};

const CONDITION = {
  condition: {
    include: [
      { name: "John" },
    ],
    exclude: [
      { name: "John" },
      { adress: "Victory st" },
    ],
  },
};

const filterByConditions = (items, conditions) => {
  // Хендлер для проверки соотвествие всего набора некоторых условий
  const _checkCondition = (_conditions, _item) => _conditions
    .every((_condition) => {
      const [_key] = Object.keys(_condition);

      return _item[_key] === _condition[_key];
    });
  // Извелкаем типы условий
  const conditionTypes = Object.keys(conditions);
  const result = [];

  items.forEach((item) => {
    // Проверяем наличие правила включения
    // Если оно имеется, то инициируем значением null
    // В ином случае мы по умолчанию должны добавлять текущий item
    let added = conditionTypes.includes('include') ? null : item;

    conditionTypes.forEach((type) => {
      // Проверяем выполнение для некоторого набора условий 'include'
      if (type === 'include' && _checkCondition(conditions[type], item)) {
        added = item;
      }
      // Проверяем выполнение для некоторого набора условий 'exclude'
      if (type === 'exclude' && _checkCondition(conditions[type], item) && added) {
        // Прореряем, равно ли текущее значение added исключаемому
        added = JSON.stringify(added) === JSON.stringify(item) ? null : item;
      }
    });

    // Если по итогу проверок мы всё ещё имеем лобавляемое, то пушим его
    if (added) {
      result.push(added);
    }
  });

  return result;
};

console.log(filterByConditions(DATA.data, CONDITION.condition));
```

Comment: Спасибо. Интересное решение

Answer (score 1):

что мешает решить задачу в лоб?

пройти по массиву и оставить только требуемые словари?

```
let data = {
     "data": [{"name": "John", "adress": "Main st", "age": 25},
              {"name": "John", "adress": "Victory st", "age": 27},
              {"name": "Jane", "adress": "5 avenue st", "age": 22}]
};

let condition = {
    "condition": {
        "include": [{"name": "John"}]
    }
};

data["data"] = data["data"].filter(element => {
    local_condition = condition["condition"];
    local_include = local_condition["include"];
    
    for (obj of local_include) {
        if (obj["name"] != undefined && element["name"].localeCompare(obj["name"]) == 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
})

console.log(data);
```